# How to perform post call/insert to multiple tables in serial order in flask with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a post call api which should insert data into multiple tables in serial order like below:

```
insert data into table_1:
--->column 1(id)
--->column 2
--->column 3
--->column 4 foreigkey(table_2.id):
       insert data into table_2
       ---> column 1(id)
       ---> column 2(address)
       ---> column 3 (latidude)
       ---> column 4 (longitude)
--->commit at table_1
```

I am using flask-sqlachemy for db connections. Please suggestion me best approach i can use to perform this operation.

I am want to insert data into child/related tables along with parent table during user submitting details.